# Исключения при попытке обратиться к несуществующему объекту

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Возникает исключение при попытке обратиться к несуществующему объекту. Хотя в контроллере я обрабатываю такую возможность.

Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/author/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAuthor(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

    if (authorService.findById(id) == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    Author author = authorService.findById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<Author>(author, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Сервис

```
public Author findById(int id) {
    return authorRepository.getOne(id);
}
```

Репозиторий

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends JpaRepository<Author,Integer> {
}
```

Сущность

```
@Entity(name = "authors")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
```

Ответ

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-04-25T17:41:06.578+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Could not write JSON: Unable to find com.example.model.Author with id 5; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unable to find com.example.model.Author with id 5 (through reference chain: com.example.model.Author_$$_jvst1b2_2[\"name\"])",
"path": "/author/5"
}
```

И ошибка

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.example.model.Author with id 5
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:244) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.permissiveInitialization(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:201) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:152) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:268) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
at com.example.model.Author_$$_jvst1b2_2.getName(Author_$$_jvst1b2_2.java) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:688) [jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) [jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) [jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) [jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:319) [jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1396) [jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:913) [jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar:2.9.5]
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:286) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:102) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:271) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:224) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) [spring-webmvc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JpaRepository.getOne()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#getOne-ID-) выбрасывает исключение, если в базе нет данных с таким `id`. Это можно решить либо перехватывая исключение:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/author/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAuthor(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

    Author author = null;
    try {
        author = authorService.findById(id);
    }
    catch (EntityNotFoundException exc) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Author>(author, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Либо в сервисе надо заменить выбрасывающий исключение `getOne` на [findById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findById-ID-) возвращающий [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html):

```
public Optional<Author> findById(int id) {
    return authorRepository.findById(id);
}
```

И тогда в контроллере исправить проверку:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/author/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAuthor(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

    Optinal<Author> author = authorService.findById(id); 
    if (!author.isPresent()) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Author>(author.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

А лучше даже так

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/author/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getAuthor(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

    return authorService.findById(id)
                        .map(author -> new ResponseEntity<Author>(author, HttpStatus.OK))
                        .orElse(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

Comment: Очень круто! Спасибо!